# Axios recupera los datos pero los carga como undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios, component

Realizo peticiones a la PokeApi y puedo recuperar los datos bien a través de axios, este me devuelve un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    name:"bulbasaur"
    url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
    name:"ivysaur"
    url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
    name:"venusaur"
    url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
}
```

Todo va bien hasta este punto, pero luego realizo una petición a la dirección que viene en la propiedad "url" y esta me devuelve un objeto con datos, entre ellos estos:

```
    {
  "base_experience": 101,
  "forms": [
    {
      "name": "ditto",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/132/"
    }
  ],
   "height": 3,
   "sprites": {
    "back_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/132.png",
    "back_female": null,
    "back_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/132.png",
    "back_shiny_female": null,
    "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/132.png",
    "front_female": null,
    "front_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/132.png",
    "front_shiny_female": null
    }
}
```

Se realiza la petición pero, cuando la quiero mostrar en una etiqueta imagen cualquiera de las fotos, me marca la propiedad sprites como undefined.

Este es el código del componente:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

export default function Pokemon(props) {
  const pokemonInfo = props.pokemonInfo;
  let imagenes = {};
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);

  const getPokemonInfo = async url => {
    const req = await axios.get(url);
    const pokeInfo = await req.data;
    console.log(`data ${JSON.stringify(pokeInfo.sprites)} END`);
    imagenes = pokeInfo.sprites;
    console.log(`imagenes ${imagenes.back_default}`);
    setPokemon(pokeInfo);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemonInfo(pokemonInfo.url);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
        <img src={imagenes.back_default} />
        <p>weight {pokemon.weight}</p>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

También anexo la url del proyecto [PokedexConReact](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-learning-react-as7pgs?file=src%2Fpages%2FPokemon.js) para una mejor comprehensión.

Comment: la propiedad sprites no existe... porque pensas que existe? sprites esta dentro de la url...

Comment: Si hay undefined en la consola, entonces no se esta asignando ningún valor a la variable imagenes, ¿Que te muestra la consola para pokeInfo? sugiero verificar que pokeInfo contenga las llaves que solicitas (sprites, back_default etc)

Comment: Es correcto no lo está asignando, cuando imprimo pokeInfo en la petición con axios se ve el objeto con sus propiedades, cuando lo imprimo fuera de, es cuando aparece undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Por que no conviertes tus imagenes en un estado, Ejemplo:

```
const[imagenes, setImagenes] = useState({});
```

2.- Luego puedes actualizar ese estado ejemplo:

```
setImagenes(pokeInfo.sprites);
```

3.- Ya estarías en condiciones de mostrar la imagen como la estas mostrando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- Intentalo y me dices que pasó.

Comment: Efectivamente, use un estado y funcionó como muestras.